# What is the effect of brown out detection on frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, brownout

I want to use ATMega16 microcontroller to strobe a flash for an industrial camera. So timing is important.
I enable BOD (brown out detection).

- Does BOD affect frequency or timing?
- If yes, is there any way or any micro or any external chip to avoid it?

Comment: BOD shouldn't effect frequency or timing, usually the BOD detection circuit is just part of the power circuitry in the chip and sets certain registers to be able to detect that during a reset event.

Comment: I here that, it can affect frequency but I'm not sure. I know that it affects power consumption that is not important for me.

Comment: If the BOD activates the output will stop or at least skip as the chip halts or restarts...

Comment: @Babak.Abad - Hi, "*I [hear] that, it can affect frequency*". If you heard this from a person, then please ask them to explain *why* they claim that, and you can add the details of their claim into your question. If you read it in a book, please add the relevant text into your question, as well as details of the book title, author & page number. As *Chris Stratton* points out, the BOR affects your MCU behaviour *when it triggers a reset*, but that is what it's supposed to do. It is your choice whether to use the BOR, after your risk assessment of the system design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly all microcontrollers have built-in Brown-out detection (BOD) circuit, which monitors supply voltage level during operation. BOD circuit is nothing more than the comparator, which compares supply voltage to a fixed trigger level. If the supply voltage goes below that level the controller will be hold in reset.

See [Brown Out Info](https://scienceprog.com/microcontroller-brown-out-detection/) for details.

To answer the question: **No**, a BOD circuit has no influence on frequency or timing.

Comment: @the busybee of course!!! good edit